# Multi-Layered Bootstrap Page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any bootstrap solution, to make a site with multi-layered pages when you scrolling? Like Torch Web Browser site do. http://torchbrowser.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your solution 
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html
Enjoy: )

Comment: That was a fast answer! Thank you very much Jyoti! :)

Comment: Your Welcome... :)